# Performance difference between RcppArmadillo and Armadillo

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to understand a difference in performance between a function written in RcppArmadillo and one written in a standalone C++ program using the Armadillo library. For example, consider the following simple function that computes the coefficients for a linear model using the traditional textbook formula.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void simpleLm(NumericMatrix Xr, NumericMatrix yr) {
   int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
   mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);
   colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.nrow(), false);

   colvec coef = inv(X.t()*X)*X.t()*y;
}
```

This takes about 6 seconds to run with a `1000000x100` matrix for `X`. Some timings in the code (not shown) indicated that all the time is spent on the `coef` calculation.

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(1000000*100), ncol=100)
y <- matrix(rep(1, 1000000))
system.time(simpleLm(X,y))

 user  system elapsed 
  6.028   0.009   6.040
```

Now consider a very similar function written in C++ that is then compiled with `g++`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 1000000;
    mat X = randu<mat>(n,100);
    vec y = ones<vec>(n);

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    colvec coef = inv(X.t()*X)*X.t()*y;

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<double, milli> diff = end - start;

    cout << diff.count() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here the calculation of the `coef` variable only takes about 0.5 seconds, or only 1/12th the time as when done with RcppArmadillo.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.2 with R 3.1.0, Rcpp 0.11.1 and RcppArmadillo 0.4.200.0. I compiled the Rcpp example using the sourceCpp function. The standalone C++ example uses Armadillo 4.200.0, and I also installed the Fortran compiler for Mac using Homebrew (`brew install gfortran`).

Comment: You didn't list the optimization flags set: if I remember correctly R (and hence sourceCpp) defaults to -O2, but you should check (try `verbose=TRUE` in `sourceCpp`). You should make sure you're compiling the stand-alone C++ file with the same optimization level as well.

Comment: Yes--R uses whatever was used when `configure; make; make install` ran, which you can override via `CXXFLAGS` and friends.  Optimization is unlikely to cause the order of magnitude Abiel saw here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick guess:  your native program uses accelerated BLAS, you R build does not.

The actual "matrix math" is farmed out by Armadillo to the BLAS library.  With RcppArmadillo, you get what R is built against.  With a native program, maybe you use something else. It could be as simple as your program getting to use the Accelerate libraries whereas R doesn't -- I don't really know as I don't use OS X.

But to demonstrate, on my (i7, Linux) machine, times are near identical.

First, your program, unaltered:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o abiel abiel.cpp -larmadillo -llapack
edd@max:/tmp$ ./abiel 
2454
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Second, your program wrapped into something R can call (see below):

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/abielviaR.cpp")
R> abielDemo()
2354.41
[1] TRUE
R>
```

About the same.

The code of `abielviaR.cpp` follows.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool abielDemo() {
    int n = 1000000;
    mat X = randu<mat>(n,100);
    vec y = ones<vec>(n);

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    colvec coef = inv(X.t()*X)*X.t()*y;
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double, milli> diff = end - start;
    Rcpp::Rcout << diff.count() << endl;

    return true;
}
```

PS You really should not compute OLS via (X'X)^(-1) X though.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, you nailed the problem. I [changed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r-sig-mac/k4rDRRdtNwE) R to use the BLAS included with Apple's Accelerate framework, and now my timings match between the two versions.